# Report viewer generating problem, definition

Tags: xml, xsd, rdlc, rdl, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Please help, I have a big problem and need to solve very soon.

I am trying to generate report with Report Viewer. I use this schema http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd.

The problem is that I can generate .rdl file but when I want to open report in excel it stucks and the error is:

"InnerException {"The report definition is not valid.  Details: The required attribute 'Name' is missing."} System.Exception {Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException}".

My generated .rdl file look like this:

http://www.filefactory.com/file/cb37a90/n/SearchToExcel634408006342588293.rdl

I think the problem is that my rdl file does not have  tag for some controls. Can anyone help me? Thanks